# Replace <a> element with value of its title attribute in a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table that I am generating that contains content loaded from a database. In some fields, I have links that are used to link an employee to their internal profile.

On ready, I clone the table and turn it into a `global` before I run `dataTables` on it so I have a clean HTML table. When the table is exported, I use `unwrap` to get rid of the html links.

In one of my fields, I am using a tooltip that shows a truncated version of the title and a full version on hover.

```
<a title="Super Long Title that is not truncated" data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor:help">Super Long Title that is...</a>
```

I need to try and figure out how I can replace the contents of that column with the `<a title="">` value rather than the `unwrapped` value which would be the truncated version. Any thoughts?

Below is the code that runs when the export button is clicked:

```
var openTickets;
openTickets = $('#openTable').clone();

// ...

$('#export').click(function() {      
    openTickets.find('a').contents().unwrap();

    // Export our table (Given html table, export to excel)
    tableToExcel.download(openTickets.html(), 'Open Tickets - Export', 'xls', 'L');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can pass a function to `replaceWith()` which returns the `title` of the `a` element, like this:

```
$('#export').click(function(){
    openTickets.find('a').replaceWith(function() {
        return $(this).prop('title');
    });
    tableToExcel.download(openTickets.html(), 'Open Tickets - Export', 'xls', 'L');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4a5ffs88/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the text for that `tags` before you `unwrap()`:

```
$('#export').click(function(){

  //Add this
  openTickets.find('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(){
     $(this).html($(this).attr('title'))
  })

  openTickets.find('a').contents().unwrap();
```